# How do I add google materials icons to a component in vs code?

Tags: material-ui, google-material-icons

I am attempting to build my first progressive web app. I am trying to make a header component in a typescript file. To do this I would like to have a couple of clickable icons. I would like to use the google material icons. What is the best way to import these?

I have tried the instructions on the google fonts page but I dont get an icon, i just get text that says menu.